# Finding Index position in DataFrame based on label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a python Data Frame how can I Find the Index number of any Label.

`df.loc['Brazil']`

I have the Label but I want to know the index number so I can use the  `df.iloc[]` method.

[image: Dataset I am working on]

Comment: pls post a sample of your dataframe

Comment: posted the dataframe sample @gtomer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': None}, index=['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Columbia'])
```

```
            col
Argentina  None
Brazil     None
Columbia   None
```

You can use `get_loc`: `df.index.get_loc('Brazil')` -> outputs `1`

However, this assumes a non duplicated index. If you have:

```
            col
Argentina  None
Brazil     None
Columbia   None
Brazil     None
```

This will output: `array([False,  True, False,  True])`.

In this case, you can use the `nonzero` method of the output numpy array:

```
>>> df.index.get_loc('Brazil').nonzero()[0]
array([1, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant label as columns, you can do

```
index = df.columns.get_loc('Brazil')
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your dataframe but suppose the column in which you are searching is 'country', then:

```
df.index[df['country'] == 'Brazil'].to_list()
```

Will give you back the index of the at which the country is Brazil